# Instancing one class in and using it´s methods in several other cpp-files

Tags: c++, class, methods, include, instance

I´m slightly going mad...

I want to use the DFRobotDFPlayerMini-Library in my Code. I structured my code in in a config.h-File for all common parameters and libs, several include-Files which should play mp3-files (here "comets"), and a main.cpp.
Without the DFRobotDFPlayerMini option everything works fine. With it, compiler drops the failure *"comets.cpp:61: undefined reference to `myDFPlayer'"*. If I do the instance in config.h, compiler drops with *"multiple definition of` myDFPlayer'"*.

How can i instance one myDFPlayer which can be used in all other cpp-files inclusive the play-method.
Thank you for an idea, hint or solution.

**SOLVED by removing nearly all includes of library**

Jennifer

Here some fragments of code for illustration:

**config.h**

```
#ifndef INITIAL_EFIRE
    #define INITIAL_EFIRE
    #include <FastLED.h> // Fastled library to control the LEDs
    extern CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
    extern CRGB leds_Shoot[NUM_LEDS_Raise];
    #include <DFRobotDFPlayerMini.h>//MP3-Player library
#endif
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <FastLED.h>       // Fastled library to control the LEDs
#include "config.h"
#include <DFRobotDFPlayerMini.h>//MP3-Player library

#include "comets.h"

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS]; //instancing common LED for FastLED-Object
DFRobotDFPlayerMini myDFPlayer; //instancing MP3-player
...
//setup MP3-player, play one file and it works.
```

**comets.h**

```
#ifndef COMETS
#define COMETS
#include <Arduino.h>

void Comet(uint32_t c, uint8_t Direction, uint8_t wait, uint8_t Shape_Num);
void Salut(uint32_t c, uint8_t wait, uint8_t Shape_Num);
#endif
```

**comets.cpp**

```
#include "config.h"
#include <DFRobotDFPlayerMini.h>//MP3-Player library

extern DFRobotDFPlayerMini myDFPlayer; //extern because it will instaced in **main.cpp**

void Comet(uint32_t c, uint8_t Direction, uint8_t wait, uint8_t Shape_Num){
  myDFPlayer.play(10);  
 ....
 }
```

Comment: is `comets` a compilation unit of program or it's part of library compiled separately? IN latter case you actually cannot compile library because it expects to have that symbol defined (e.g. as imported one, at least). Otherwise something odd is going on with build process. Also, it's good to read about singletons

Comment: Is the compiler or the linker giving that message? Can you provide the full command line to the failing invocation?

Comment: @Swift - Friday Pie:

Comment: @Swift - Friday Pie: comets is a include-file, where i include LED-effects and sound-output (mp3)  for main.cpp. The funny thing is, that if i comment out all play-methods in comet.cpp, compiler finish without failure and i can instance and use the myDFPlayer.play method in main.cpp. But structure of program will be bad.

Comment: @Artefacto: it´s the compiler. I used Arduino IDE and Visual Studio Code/platformIO, with the same result.

Comment: BRRRREAK! I found my mistake in code after sleeping about it. There were too much includes of the library in code.  So my problem is solved. :-) Dammed! i sitted yesterday whole day fixing the problem..

Comment: @Jenny  a nonstatic instance ofc shouldn't be declared in header file, because it then would be created in each unit that includes that file, that's clearly an ODR breach.  A static or const one will be present as separate entity in each unit, that's not something you'd want in this case. If you need only single copy of an object, a singleton done Meyer's way is indeed a way to avoid that if you want a header-only solution.